# iOS - Building VLC for iOS - Please install required SDK, or set SDKROOT manually

Tags: iphone, ios6, vlc, ios5.1, libvlc

I have upgraded my xcode to 4.5, now I am **Building VLC for iOS** and countered that SDK version 5.1 not found. I have fully installed all the sdk's in my xcode 4.5

```
Mac-Muhammad-Umair-Mirza:vlc muhammad.umair$ ./extras/package/ios/build.sh
[info] Building libvlc for the iOS
[info] Using armv7 with SDK version 5.1
usage: dirname path
SDKROOT not specified, assuming /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
*** /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk does not exist, please install required SDK, or set SDKROOT manually. ***
```

Please help me out in finding the solution.

Comment: May be you should select in xcode build with Latest SDK and run your script?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
export /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS*.*.sdk
```

where "*.*" is your current SDK (for instance 6.1).