# VideoLan VLC iOS sdk Compiling Error

Tags: ios, vlc

I am following this step by step procedure to compile the code

https://wiki.videolan.org/iOSCompile

But At this step
"sh buildAspenProject.sh -s"

I am getting following error
"iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk does not exist, please install required SDK, or set SDKROOT manually"

Please help how to set SDKROOT Manully

Comment: What version os XCode do you have ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741716/ios-building-vlc-for-ios-please-install-required-sdk-or-set-sdkroot-manuall

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the build script manually and simply replace "6.1" with whatever SDK is available on your Mac. Note that VLC for iOS 2.0 and higher were never tested with SDKs prior to 5.1.

Additionally, after the build script cloned the "vlc" repository in ImportedSources/vlc, you'll need to do a similar modification to /ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios/build.sh as it also assumes the 6.1 SDK to be present.